# About deformations of Lie algebra structures and Nijenhuis bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, tensors

In a previous post [Lie bracket as a tensor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213825/lie-bracket-as-a-tensor) I asked about the formalism of deformed Lie brackets, how a tensor could satisfy the Leibniz rule. This is question is solved and now I want a proof of the next result:

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional manifold and let $[\cdot,\cdot]$ be the usual Lie bracket of the $\mathbb R$-algebra of vector fields over $M$. Consider an endomorphism $N\in \Gamma^{\infty}(TM\otimes T^*M)$. Then, the bracket

$$
[X,Y]_N = [N(X),Y] + [X,N(Y)] - N([X,Y])
$$

satisfies the Jacobi identity (and then defines a Lie bracket) if and only if $N$ is a Nijenhuis tensor, i.e.

$$
\frac{1}{2}[N,N]_{FN}(X,Y) = [N(X),N(Y)]-N([N(X),Y]) - N([X,N(Y)]) + N^2([X,Y]) = 0
$$

for all $X,Y$ in $\Gamma^{\infty}(TM)$.

One proof can be found in Deformations on Lie algebra structures, of A. Nijenhuis and R. W. Richardson, (1967), publised on *Journal of Mathematics and Mechanics*, T. **17**, No. 1, pp. 89-105.

However, I have been looking for at Internet and i have not found anything. And also, the library of my university neither have it.

EDIT___________________________________________

After big efforts and many computations finally I founded this equality:

$$
\oint_{X,Y,Z} [X,[Y,Z]_N]_N = -\frac{1}{2} \oint_{X,Y,Z} \Bigg(T_N(X,[Y,Z]) + [X, T_N(Y,Z)] \Bigg) ,
$$

where I am naming

$$
T_N(X,Y) = \frac{1}{2} [N,N]_{FN}(X,Y)
$$

and

$$
\oint_{X,Y,Z} f(X,Y,Z) = f(X,Y,Z) + f(Y,Z,X) + f(Z,X,Y)
$$

the cyclic sum that appears in the Jacobi identity.

So one direction is clear. But, I am not sure

$$
\oint_{X,Y,Z} \Bigg(T_N(X,[Y,Z]) + [X, T_N(Y,Z)] \Bigg) = 0
$$

implies

$$
T_N(X,Y)=0
$$

for all vector fields $X$ and $Y$.

Can anybody helps me?

Thanks.

Comment: Another perfect answer would be a photo (or pdf) with the original proof of the paper or a link to download the pdf

Comment: You can just compute the Jacobi identity for $[X,Y]_N$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the computation was hard and it is not enough. Some extra idea is necessary. See my edit please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well... as is usual, I will answer my own question. The statement is more general than my question. In fact, $(TM,[\cdot,\cdot]_N,N)$ is a Lie algebroid if and only if $N$ is a Nijenhuis operatoor. The proof is as follows.

First, check $N$ is a homomorphism if and only if $T_N=0$:

$$
N([X,Y]_N)= N([N(X),Y]) + N([X,N(Y)]) - N^2([X,Y]) = [N(X),N(Y)] \, , \quad \forall X,Y\in{\frak X}(M) \, .
$$
This expresion is equivaent to say $T_N=0$.

After, consider the derivation $D$ defined on $T^*M$ by means of this new bracket and the anchor map $N$:

$$
D \alpha \, (X_1,\dots, X_{p+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{p+1} (-1)^{i+1} N(X_i)(\alpha(X_1,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,X_{p+1}) + \sum_{i<j} (-1)^{i+j} \alpha([X_i,X_j]_N,X_1,\dots,\hat{X}_i,\dots,\hat{X}_j,\dots,X_{p+1}) \, .
$$

As a derivation of degree 1, it can be write as (Frölicher-Nijenhuis decomposition theorem)

$$
D = \mathcal{L}_K + i_L 
$$

where $K$ is $TM$-valued 1-form and $L$ is a $TM$-valued 2-form. Studing the behavior of $D$ over functions and 1-forms one can see that $L=0$ and $K=N$, so

$$
D=\mathcal{L}_N \, .
$$

Finally we have to study the operator $\mathcal{L}^2_N$. We know

$$
\mathcal{L}^2_N = 0 \Longleftrightarrow T_N = 0 \, ,
$$

since

$$
T_N=\frac{1}{2} [N,N]_{FN} = \frac{1}{2} [\mathcal{L}_N,\mathcal{L}_N](f) = \mathcal{L}_N^2 (f) \, .
$$

A short computation shows

$$
D^2\alpha (X,Y,Z) = \mathcal{L}^2_N \alpha(X,Y,Z) = \oint_{X,Y,Z} N([X,Y])(\alpha(Z) ) - \oint_{X,Y,Z} [N(X),N(Y)](\alpha(Z)) + \oint_{X,Y,Z} \alpha([[X,Y]_N,Z]_N) \, ,
$$

thus

$$
\oint_{X,Y,Z} \alpha([[X,Y]_N,Z]_N)  = 0 \Longleftrightarrow N([X,Y]_N)= N([N(X),Y]) + N([X,N(Y)]) - N^2([X,Y]) = [N(X),N(Y)] \Longleftrightarrow T_N = 0
$$